# Issue with jQuery .animate command

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was using the animate command for jQuery and for some reason this doesn't work:

```
$('#my_div_id').animate({left:'calc(50% + 50px)'}, 1000);
```

Is there any way to get around this?

I know the code works if i put '50%', or '50px', but I want my div to animate to 50% of the screen + 50px.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that `calc` cannot be animated, but fortunately it's easy for you to calculate 50% of the width of the screen already since you have the power of JavaScript.

```
$("#my_div_id").animate({left: $("body").width() / 2 + 50 + "px"}, 1000);
```

This assumes that `#my_div_id` is positioned relative to the `body` (i.e. no relative position ancestory -- otherwise you would have to use that).

Comment: 1+ I was about to post a variant of this.. using `$(this).parent().width()`.... `$("#my_div_id").animate({left: $(this).parent().width() / 2 + 50 + "px"}, 1000);`

Comment: Ok, got it. However what if i wanted 30%? of the screen, i would have to  do 
    (3 / 10) * $('body').width()

Comment: @user3399686 I don't see why that wouldn't work, or just `* .3`

Answer (score 0):

Basically nothing new, but using the explicit request of the asker, to set it to 50% of the screen width:

```
var width = screen.width / 2 + 50;
$('#my_div_id').animate({left: width + "px"}, 1000);
```